# Dual boot partition issue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

After a failed upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04, I reinstalled from a live CD. I believe this resulted in the creation of another partition duting the reinstall. In addition, I am no longer able to boot my Windows OS and can only boot into 16.04, however I am still able to access files from Windows as well as my initial installation of Ubuntu.

```
    Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
    /dev/sda1        2048    2050047    2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
    /dev/sda2     2050048    2582527     532480   260M EFI System
    /dev/sda3     2582528    4630527    2048000  1000M Lenovo boot partition
    /dev/sda4     4630528    4892671     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
    /dev/sda5     4892672 1732583423 1727690752 823.8G Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sda6  1866801152 1919229951   52428800    25G Microsoft basic data
    /dev/sda7  1919229952 1953523711   34293760  16.4G Windows recovery environment
    /dev/sda8  1732583424 1733070847     487424   238M Linux filesystem
    /dev/sda9  1733070848 1737070591    3999744   1.9G Linux swap
    /dev/sda10 1737070592 1737072639       2048     1M BIOS boot
    /dev/sda11 1801070592 1866801151   65730560  31.4G Linux filesystem
    /dev/sda12 1737072640 1801070591   63997952  30.5G Linux filesystem
```

[image]

---

UPDATE:

I ran an Ubuntu live-CD to use boot-repair. Here is my [BootInfo URL](http://paste2.org/K0ePNMxO/)

UPDATE #2
After boot-repair, I was able to access Windows using the grub menu. However, I was unable to access my Ubuntu filesystem. Using Disk Manager in Windows, I deleted partitions sd8-12 and extended sd5.

Comment: Yes you must have chosen to install "along side Windows" and you had a lot of unallocated space on disk. If you had chosen to install into the existing partition, it would have only used that  partition, and kept the /home. However... looking at it again... I see **three** Linux partitions... did you do this more that once, or do you have other Linux installations on this disk? Regarding Windows boot, I assume that you don't see Windows in the GRUB menu, yes?

Comment: ah... try and use boot-repair to solve the Windows boot issue. Search here on AskUbuntu for boot-repair, or "Boot Repair", for instructions on how to use the Ubuntu Live DVD to run boot-repair. Cheers, Al ps: post a screenshot of gparted view of your hard disk.

Comment: That partition table is a mess :(

Comment: @heynnema I will give that a shot. However, I am not sure what I should do with the partitions I am not using at the moment. To be completely honest, I don't even know the purpose of each individual partition

Comment: @AndroidDev any advice on how to clean it up?

Comment: I looked at your gparted snap. Don't even know where to start... sigh. I'd backup any documents you have in Ubuntu, delete partitions sda8-12, resize sda5, and reinstall Ubuntu from scratch. If this sounds like a lot of work, and high risk for errors, you're correct. I can't talk you through it here. Cheers, Al

Comment: It also looks like your reinstall was BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode as now you also have a bios_grub partition. That is only required for BIOS boot and grub installed to gpt's protective MBR. And UEFI and BIOS are not compatible, so once you start booting in one mode you cannot change. Or from grub menu you an only boot other systems in same UEFI or BIOS boot mode. You can to reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode, and how you boot install media is then how it installs.  Shows both BIOS & UEFI screens:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: @heynnema if you could be so kind, is there a different channel of communication you could talk me through the process?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the fix'in is way too complicated, and I can't spend more time than I already have. See if you can find a local Linux guru to sit down in front of the machine to help you. High schools and colleges are full of students probably willing to help. Just post a note in their school newspaper, or on their "cork" board. Give them a copy of my last suggestion as a place to start. Good luck. Al

Comment: The `BootInfo URL` you added does not work; Maybe you can add it as a code section - then it gets a scrollbox if it is  long. (Start each line with four spaces)

Comment: reinstall windows using recovery disks then free up space for Ubuntu using Disk-Manager Then  try `boot-repair`  from live Cd UEFI mode.if  unsuccessful than edit your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi/228069#228069

Comment: install alongside windows if you get this option.

Comment: grub-customizer is also good.

Answer (score -1):

That stupid UEFI always spoils everything even on updated machines.
If you want to try more Linux distros *please,* use legacy MBR mode.

I'm going to tell you how to clean up that mess.
First of all you need to restore the windows boot manager, and please don't upgrade your system unless Windows is your only OS in the machine.

What you'll need:

1. No more than 5 hours
2. A device with Windows.iso
3. A device with Ubuntu.iso

Burn a CD/DVD or use a USB with [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/?locale=us) for your [Windows.iso](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) boot the device, enter to repair > advanced options > command prompt type this:

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

That will restore windows and you will be able to access your files (please make a backup of your files with an external HDD and save your windows licence on a paper).
Boot windows and please remove all that ubuntu stuff in the Partition Manager, you will be able to delete all that is not windows.
Then for restore ubuntu insert the ubuntu.iso media and boot as live image, open the terminal(make sure that the name of your HDD typing ´lsblk´ and type this.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

That's all

Comment: if you are stuck in ubuntu just use another computer from your family or whatever go a cyber I dunno. Rufus is the only program I know that works perfect, another programsjust doesnt work